# What exactly was the Hydrogen Wave Crisis of 1972?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

In *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* season 5 episode 11 "All the Comforts of Home", a projected recording of Rick Stoner explains that the Lighthouse was built in case of an extinction level event. Phil Coulson then mentions that the "1972 Hydrogen Wave Crisis" was averted and therefore there was no need to use the Lighthouse. However, I can't find a (real life *or* in-universe) description of what this was. Did it actually happen? Is it explained somewhere else? Or was this just a throwaway line to make us ask questions?

Comment: Maybe this? https://www.realclearscience.com/blog/2019/09/12/the_fear_that_a_nuclear_bomb_could_ignite_the_atmosphere.html

Comment: "I can't find a […] description of what this was." – That means S.H.I.E.L.D. did its job well.

Comment: Rewatching AOS right now! It comes back as a little reference/easter egg in S7E6. Other than that it seems disposable